# Get the array of items. Use CCMenu::createWithArray

Tags: c++, arrays, cocos2d-x

please help me, im a beginner in cocos2d-x.
i have the list of items.
how can i do this using array of items, using CCMenu::createWithArray to show this list at the end?
i want to control the menu array, to add/drop items from array(from my list menu).

here is the code:

``
    ...

```
CCLabelTTF* pp0BtnLabel = CCLabelTTF::create( string(ItemName[0]).c_str(), "Arial", TITLE_FONT_SIZE);   
CCMenuItemLabel *pp0Item = CCMenuItemLabel::create(
            pp0BtnLabel,
            this,
            menu_selector(Window::CheckItemCallback));
pp0Item->setTag(ItemTag[0]);    
CC_BREAK_IF(! pp0Item);
pp0Item->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.3f, size.height*0.8));

CCLabelTTF* pp1BtnLabel = CCLabelTTF::create( string(ItemName[0]).c_str(), "Arial", TITLE_FONT_SIZE);   
CCMenuItemLabel *pp1Item = CCMenuItemLabel::create(
            pp1BtnLabel,
            this,
            menu_selector(Window::CheckItemCallback));
pp1Item->setTag(ItemTag[0]);    
CC_BREAK_IF(! pp1Item);
pp1Item->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.3f, size.height*0.75));

CCLabelTTF* pp2BtnLabel = CCLabelTTF::create( string(ItemName[0]).c_str(), "Arial", TITLE_FONT_SIZE);   
CCMenuItemLabel *pp2Item = CCMenuItemLabel::create(
            pp2BtnLabel,
            this,
            menu_selector(Window::CheckItemCallback));
pp2Item->setTag(ItemTag[0]);    
CC_BREAK_IF(! pp2Item);
pp2Item->setPosition(ccp(size.width*0.3f, size.height*0.7));

CCMenu* pMenuChapter = CCMenu::create(pp0Item, pp1Item, pp2Item, NULL);
pMenuChapter->setPosition(CCPointZero);
CC_BREAK_IF(! pMenuChapter);

this->addChild(pMenuChapter, 1);

            ...
```

``

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question... but here is how you can create a CCMenu using a CCArray.

```
CCLabelTTF*label = CCLabelTTF::create("label text", "Arial", 32);

CCMenuItemLabel *item1 = CCMenuItemLabel::create(label, this, menu_selector(CPhysicsLayer::itemCallback));
CCMenuItemLabel *item2 = CCMenuItemLabel::create(label, this, menu_selector(CPhysicsLayer::itemCallback));
CCMenuItemLabel *item3 = CCMenuItemLabel::create(label, this, menu_selector(CPhysicsLayer::itemCallback));

CCArray*array = CCArray::create(item1, item2, item3);
CCMenu*menu = CCMenu::createWithArray(array);

/// Iterate over the menu items
CCObject*obj = NULL;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(array, obj) {
    CCMenuItemLabel*item = (CCMenuItemLabel*)obj;
    /// Do something with the item...
}
```

To add item to the menu at "run-time" then use the CCMenu::addChild method (and removeChild to remove the item).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote if you find the anwser useful  ;)